# Rxjs: How to use bufferTime while only triggering an emission when new values have arrived

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am using bufferTime to react to resize events:

```
this.resizeSubject.pipe(bufferTime(100)).subscribe((data)=>{
  console.log(data);
});
```

data is generated on window resize:

```
  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
    let innerWidth = event.target.innerWidth;
    this.resizeSubject.next(innerWidth);
  }
```

The problem with is that `bufferTime` emits a value (empty array) every 100ms even though next was not called. I could do a comparison in the subscribe function, but I imagine there must be an option to release the buffered value after 100ms only if a new value arrived. If `next` was called 10 times in 100ms, the expected emitted value is just one array of 10 items. If after that `next` is not called, the subscriber is given no new data.

What option should I use to tell `rxjs` that it should emit every 100ms only if a new value has arrived?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your use case, [`auditTime`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/audittime) might be the simplest solution. `auditTime` is similar to `bufferTime`, but only releases the last value that arrived within the defined time frame, and if no value arrived, no value is emitted:

```
this.resizeSubject.pipe(
    auditTime(100)
)
.subscribe(data => { console.log(data); });
```

PS: Based on the code you showed, you want to track the resizing of a window. If multiple size-values arrive within a short time frame, it might indeed make sense to process only the last one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`filter`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter) to prevent emissions that are empty:

```js
this.resizeSubject.pipe(
  bufferTime(100),
  filter(arr => arr.length > 0)
).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```